# ThreadPool not releasing memory?

Tags: python, memory, threadpool

When using Python's `ThreadPool` to parallelize a CPU-intensive task it seems like memory used by the workers is accumulated and not released. I've tried to simplified the problem:

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def worker(x):
    # Bloat the memory footprint of this function
    a = x ** x
    b = a + x
    c = x / b
    return hash(c.tobytes())   

tasks = (np.random.rand(1000, 1000) for _ in range(500))

with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
    for result in pool.imap(worker, tasks):
        assert result is not None
```

When running this snippet one can easily observe a huge jump in the memory footprint Python uses. However I would have expected this to have nearly the same behavior as

```py
for task in tasks:
    assert worker(task) is not None
```

whose memory cost is negligible.

How do I have to modify the snippet to apply the `worker` function to each array using a `ThreadPool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the explanation is quite simple. Modifying the the example to create the random array only inside the worker will solve the problem:

```py
def worker(x):
    x = x()
    # Bloat the memory footprint of this function
    a = x ** x
    b = a + x
    c = x / b
    return hash(c.tobytes())

tasks = (lambda: np.random.rand(1000, 1000) for _ in range(500))
```

It seems like `ThreadPools.imap` will internally turn the generator `tasks` into a list or something alike. This would of course require to store all 500 random arrays in memory at once.